# Vishnu Purana, 1st Amsha, chapter 4 Shloka 35, refers to Varaha as "one who enveloped earth in 1 step". How can Vamana reference come?

Tags: puranas, vishnu-purana, vamana, varaha

Vishnu Purana, 1st Amsha, chapter 4 Shloka 35 (पदक्रमक्रांता भुवम), refers to Varaha as "one who enveloped earth in 1 step". Can someone please explain as to how Vamana avatar reference comes here when praising Varaha avatar

Comment: As per my understanding Puranas were written later when all the incidents already happened. So if we see that way it is possible that the author took the freedom of praising Lord Vishnu by giving reference of Vamana Avatar.